# How can I call PipeTransform with parameters in async way in template?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In Angular I am using PipeTransform which has some logic in it and return data object. But when use it I get this error *ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError*. I read that calling in async may solve the problem.

How can I call PipeTransform with parameters in async way in template?

Here is the Pipe code:

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'userCalculation })
export class UserCalculationToStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public userCalculationModel: UserCalculationModel = new UserCalculationModel('', '', 0);
    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {}
    transform(employeeDay: EmployeeDayModel, resultType: ShowingCalculationItemModel, args?: string): any {

        if (employeeDay) {
            if (resultType.Type == CalculationItemType.PrevalentCategory) {
                if (employeeDay.PrevalentCategory) {
                    this.userCalculationModel.IconId = employeeDay.PrevalentCategory.IconId;
                }
                return this.userCalculationModel;
            }

            if (resultType.Type == CalculationItemType.PendingApprovedAbsences) {
                this.userCalculationModel.Status = 0;

                if (employeeDay.Absences && employeeDay.Absences.length === 0) {
                    return this.userCalculationModel;
                }

                this.userCalculationModel.IconId = employeeDay.Absences[0].IconId;

                if (employeeDay.Absences[0].Status == ApprovalStatus.Pending) {
                    this.userCalculationModel.Status = 1;
                    let hoverTitle = "Hover test";
                    this.userCalculationModel.Title = hoverTitle;
                }

                return this.userCalculationModel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and usage in template:

```html
<div *ngIf="day.value | userCalculation: selectedCalculation; let item">
    {{ item.Status }}
</div>
```

Comment: can you paste a little of your code here? At least transform method from pipe and example of usage.

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: How does `selectedCalculation` work in your component?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas this is just parameter that I put to Pipe. I didn't copy whole pipe code there.

Comment: I'm asking because there's nothing async going from the code you provided. Giving more information on what component does would help us help you.

Comment: Then is the question why I get the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error?